# Powershell Get-Netadapter varible pass to Set-DnsClientServerAddress

Tags: powershell, scripting, adapter

Good day everyone,

Trying to write a simple script that will find the friendly name of the Ethernet Adapter on a given machine and pass this string to the cmdlet 'Set-DnsClientServerAddress' so that I can change the DNS server settings on the Ethernet interface only.

I have tried this:

```
$EthAdapter = Get-NetAdapter -Name Ether* | select Name | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2 -PassThru
```

And get the error:

> Set-DnsClientServerAddress : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.                                   At C:\users\zsnow\Desktop\setup.ps1:5 char:59                                                                                         + ... lect Name | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1,  ...                                                       +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                               + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{Name=Ethernet 2}:PSObject) [Set-DnsClientServerAddress], ParameterBindingException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Set-DnsClientServerAddress

I have tried this:

```
$EthAdapter = Get-NetAdapter -Name Ether* | select Name
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $EthAdapter -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2 -PassThru
```

And get this error:

> Set-DnsClientServerAddress : No MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress objects found with property 'InterfaceAlias' equal to '@{Name=Ethernet
>   2}'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
>   At C:\users\zsnow\Desktop\setup.ps1:6 char:1
>   + Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $EthAdapter -ServerAddress ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Name=Ethernet 2}:String) [Set-DnsClientServerAddress], CimJobException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_InterfaceAlias,Set-DnsClientServerAddress

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
$EthAdapters = Get-NetAdapter -Name Ether*
foreach ($EthAdapter in $EthAdapters)
{
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2 -PassThru -InterfaceAlias $EthAdapter.name -Verbose
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your original post, you either need "select -expandproperty name" instead of "select name" in your first command, or $ethadapter.name in the second command. one or the other, not both. the way you have it written, $ethadapter is an array with one column called "name", so your dns command is trying to make a change on an adapter named, literally '@{Name=Ethernet 2}'. which doesn't exist.